# Custom master page not working for visitor user in Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-server, central-administration, custom-masterpage, design-manager

I have created custom master page with css files using design manager method.the users with member permission can see all the styles in the site pages and master page, but the user with visitor permission styles are not loaded unless the files are published, But for seattle master everything working fine.In custom master page it's not, any one know the root cause for this issue? How to resolve this issue without publishing all files?

Comment: As you mentioned "unless the files are published". It is the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Users with read permission doesn't have the right to read files and documents in draft mode and minor versions. Users with contribute permission level can see draft mode and minor versions. That's why you need to publish files before visitors (with read permission only) can access the updated major version (1.0, 2.0, 3.0 and so on).

If you don't have a published version of a file and it's highest version is 0.*, the file will be inaccessible to visitors until you publish the file to a major version.